# Wants to remove the filtered values equal zero

Tags: r, filtering, data-cleaning

I have filtered a column and now have a lot of Companies which have a value of 0. My problem is that I can't remove them and now have a lot of data I don't want to use.

I have filtered that the companies should have more than 15 cases.

`dat1<-dat %>% group_by(Company) %>% filter(n()>15)`

Now as you can see below, I get a summary where the companies with less than 15 is zero.
How can I clean up my data so I only have the data where dat1$Company is different from zero?

[image]

I assume it is an easy fix but I can't get any thing to work without an error.

I have tried the which function but I get an error regarding the columns length.

Below is a sample of my data. As an example I want to remove the row containing Visitmors/U002FMorsø Turiskbüro since that company doesn't appear more than 15 times in the data.

I want to remove all the company names that has the value 0 after I have filtered. If I use `dat1<-dat1[dat1$Company != 0,]` those companies is still there. I assume that is because the company name is different from zero, and I want to remove all the companies who has less than 15 lines in the dataset.

I have following code:

`` dat$`House type`<-as.factor(dat$`House type`)
dat$Company<-as.factor(dat$Company)
dat1<-dat %>% group_by(Company) %>% filter(n()>15)
dat1<-dat1[dat1$Company != 0,] ``

[image]

````
structure(list(Region = c("Rømø", "Bornholm", "Falster", "Bornholm", 
"Südwestjütland", "Nordwestjütland", "Westjütland", "Limfjord", 
"Südostjütland", "Lolland", "Fünen", "Westjütland", "Nordostjütland", 
"Rømø", "Lolland", "Südostjütland", "Seeland", "Lolland", "Westjütland", 
"Falster"), `House type` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Ferienhaus", class = "factor"), 
    Pool = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Company = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("DanCenter", 
    "Novasol", "Sonne und Strand", "Visitmors\\u002FMorsø Turistbüro"
    ), class = "factor"), P50 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "449.00", "409.00", 
    "330.00", "368.46", "426.41", "350.00", "-1", "-1", "-1"), 
    P51 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "284.00", "-1", "389.00", 
    "1042.58", "1159.00", "-1", "-1", "779.00", "594.00", "810.00", 
    "443.79", "701.59", "850.00", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P52 = c("-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "604.00", "-1", "824.00", "1042.58", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "1154.00", "594.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1"), P1 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "683.41", "-1", "-1", "-1", "449.00", "409.00", 
    "320.00", "-1", "426.41", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P2 = c("-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "449.00", "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1"), P3 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", 
    "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "449.00", 
    "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "426.41", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"
    ), P4 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", "-1", "269.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "449.00", "409.00", "330.00", 
    "-1", "426.41", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P5 = c("-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "224.00", "-1", "264.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "449.00", "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "426.41", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P6 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "524.00", 
    "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "465.17", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"
    ), P7 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", 
    "599.00", "-1", "-1", "449.00", "409.00", "330.00", "-1", 
    "426.41", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P8 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "224.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", 
    "-1", "449.00", "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "426.41", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1"), P9 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", 
    "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "449.00", 
    "409.00", "330.00", "368.46", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"
    ), P10 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "254.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "399.00", "409.00", "330.00", 
    "368.46", "-1", "-1", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P11 = c("-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "524.00", "409.00", "330.00", "368.46", "426.41", 
    "-1", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P12 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "229.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "524.00", "409.00", "330.00", "368.46", "426.41", "-1", "284.00", 
    "-1", "-1"), P13 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "734.00", "409.00", 
    "330.00", "368.46", "426.41", "-1", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), 
    P14 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "683.41", 
    "799.00", "-1", "-1", "889.00", "-1", "-1", "455.98", "701.59", 
    "-1", "289.00", "-1", "-1"), P15 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "464.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "314.00", "683.41", "799.00", "-1", "-1", "734.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "368.46", "465.17", "-1", "314.00", "-1", "-1"
    ), P16 = c("461.00", "-1", "-1", "464.00", "264.00", "-1", 
    "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "474.00", "409.00", 
    "359.00", "368.46", "426.41", "-1", "304.00", "-1", "-1"), 
    P17 = c("461.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "289.00", "-1", "264.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "629.00", "409.00", "359.00", 
    "368.46", "426.41", "-1", "309.00", "-1", "-1"), P18 = c("490.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "439.00", "249.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", 
    "599.00", "-1", "-1", "629.00", "409.00", "359.00", "368.46", 
    "465.17", "-1", "299.00", "-1", "-1"), P19 = c("-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "524.00", "224.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "594.00", "359.00", "368.46", "426.41", 
    "-1", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P20 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "579.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "314.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "594.00", "-1", "-1", "465.17", "-1", "294.00", "-1", "-1"
    ), P21 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "314.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "594.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "289.00", "-1", "-1"), P22 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "314.00", "683.41", "799.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "594.00", "359.00", "-1", "465.17", "529.00", "299.00", 
    "-1", "-1"), P23 = c("-1", "1047.53", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "319.00", "683.41", "799.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "594.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "465.17", "529.00", "299.00", "-1", "-1"), P24 = c("-1", 
    "632.64", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "314.00", "683.41", "799.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "594.00", "-1", "368.46", "-1", "529.00", 
    "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P25 = c("762.00", "632.64", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "314.00", "893.48", "799.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "594.00", "-1", "368.46", "465.17", "570.00", "299.00", 
    "1214.62", "-1"), P26 = c("-1", "987.58", "-1", "-1", "414.00", 
    "-1", "459.00", "893.48", "1160.00", "1099.00", "-1", "664.00", 
    "579.00", "-1", "-1", "882.44", "923.00", "339.00", "1483.66", 
    "1005.96"), P27 = c("-1", "-1", "1248.19", "-1", "769.00", 
    "-1", "924.00", "1042.58", "1200.00", "1290.00", "-1", "1129.00", 
    "894.00", "820.00", "-1", "1063.91", "1009.00", "624.00", 
    "1758.65", "1301.57"), P28 = c("-1", "-1", "1248.19", "-1", 
    "949.00", "-1", "1059.00", "1042.58", "1200.00", "1290.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "954.00", "889.00", "-1", "1114.48", "-1", "784.00", 
    "-1", "-1"), P29 = c("1296.00", "-1", "1248.19", "-1", "1014.00", 
    "-1", "1059.00", "1042.58", "1200.00", "1290.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "954.00", "889.00", "-1", "1114.48", "-1", "824.00", "-1", 
    "-1"), P30 = c("1296.00", "1364.52", "1248.19", "-1", "994.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "1042.58", "1200.00", "1290.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "934.00", "889.00", "-1", "1114.48", "970.00", "734.00", 
    "-1", "-1"), P31 = c("1240.00", "1300.57", "1248.19", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "989.00", "1042.58", "1200.00", "-1", "-1", "1129.00", 
    "894.00", "889.00", "-1", "1063.91", "1116.00", "669.00", 
    "-1", "-1"), P32 = c("897.00", "1210.62", "1248.19", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "893.48", "1020.00", "879.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "774.00", "820.00", "-1", "973.77", "680.00", "534.00", "1649.13", 
    "-1"), P33 = c("713.00", "987.58", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "799.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "579.00", "810.00", 
    "-1", "882.44", "569.00", "344.00", "-1", "-1"), P34 = c("-1", 
    "687.59", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "683.41", "799.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "594.00", "810.00", "-1", "701.59", "529.00", 
    "304.00", "-1", "788.92"), P35 = c("-1", "632.64", "615.26", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "594.00", "359.00", "380.65", "465.17", "429.00", "309.00", 
    "1214.62", "-1"), P36 = c("489.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "594.00", 
    "359.00", "-1", "-1", "429.00", "319.00", "1214.62", "-1"
    ), P37 = c("489.00", "-1", "-1", "609.00", "269.00", "-1", 
    "354.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "629.00", "594.00", 
    "359.00", "-1", "-1", "429.00", "284.00", "1214.62", "-1"
    ), P38 = c("460.00", "-1", "-1", "609.00", "299.00", "-1", 
    "409.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "629.00", "594.00", 
    "359.00", "368.46", "465.17", "429.00", "289.00", "-1", "-1"
    ), P39 = c("489.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "299.00", "-1", "409.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "629.00", "594.00", "359.00", 
    "368.46", "465.17", "429.00", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P40 = c("460.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "609.00", "-1", "-1", "374.00", "683.41", "799.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "739.00", "594.00", "359.00", "368.46", "465.17", 
    "529.00", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P41 = c("497.00", "-1", 
    "-1", "914.00", "-1", "-1", "384.00", "683.41", "799.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "889.00", "594.00", "359.00", "443.79", "701.59", 
    "569.00", "289.00", "-1", "-1"), P42 = c("370.00", "-1", 
    "-1", "609.00", "-1", "-1", "359.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "734.00", "594.00", "330.00", "380.65", "465.17", 
    "429.00", "284.00", "-1", "-1"), P43 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "354.00", "-1", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "594.00", "-1", "-1", "465.17", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"), 
    P44 = c("370.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "259.00", "-1", "274.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "474.00", "409.00", "-1", 
    "-1", "426.41", "350.00", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P45 = c("370.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "259.00", "-1", "264.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "589.00", "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "-1", "350.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1"), P46 = c("370.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "244.00", 
    "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "589.00", 
    "409.00", "330.00", "-1", "-1", "350.00", "-1", "-1", "-1"
    ), P47 = c("370.00", "-1", "-1", "-1", "224.00", "-1", "254.00", 
    "683.41", "599.00", "-1", "-1", "589.00", "409.00", "330.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "350.00", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P48 = c("-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "224.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "599.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "589.00", "409.00", "330.00", "368.46", "426.41", 
    "350.00", "-1", "-1", "-1"), P49 = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "224.00", "-1", "254.00", "683.41", "659.00", "-1", "-1", 
    "449.00", "409.00", "330.00", "368.46", "426.41", "350.00", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    Company = structure(c(58L, 205L, 245L, 290L), .Label = c("-1", 
    "240 sqm2 Hotel Apartment in CPH Center", "Agger Tange Feriecenter", 
    "Allan Lindholm Andreassen", "Allan Valentin Hansen", "Anders Bentien", 
    "Anders Eskling", "Anders Heidemann", "Anders Thomassen", 
    "Anette Stagstrup", "Anita", "Anna bauer Andersen", "Anne and Tommaso", 
    "Annette Grønkær", "Aparthotel Bølshavn 9", "Apartments - Hejren", 
    "Apartments Bandholm", "Arne Andersen", "Arne Christensen", 
    "Arthur Aparts", "Asa Hildur Baldvinsdottir", "Askegaarden Apartments", 
    "Assem & Jesper", "Athome Apartments", "Ballen Havehuset", 
    "Ballen Strandpark Apartments", "Benjamin Schmitt", "Betina Nissen", 
    "Betina Robertsen", "Bettina Lauritzen", "Birgit Hoffmann", 
    "Birgith & Hans Tørsleff", "Birgitte Douglas", "Birgitte Reinhold Jakobsen", 
    "Blokhus Golfcenter", "Bo Madsen", "Bo Tune", "Bobakka", 
    "Bodil Frederiksen", "Britt Salling", "Camilla Gravgaard", 
    "Carlo", "Carsten Thomsen", "Casper Friis", "Catherina", 
    "Cecilie og Stig Ommundsen", "Central & New Nordic CPH Apartment", 
    "Central 4 bedroom apt. for big groups", "Charlotte Hyttel Henningsen Bigan", 
    "Christer Bell", "Christina Lindholm", "Claus Bork", "Connie Nielson", 
    "Connie Vestergaard", "CPH Boutique Hotel Apartments", "D.Tettinger", 
    "Dan Jensen", "DanCenter", "David", "Designer-home 50m. from Nyhavn", 
    "Diana og Kenneth Madsen", "Diana Schæffer", "Dinesen Collection - 3BR Pure LUX By New Harbour", 
    "dk-ferien Aps", "dk-ferien Ferienhausvermittlung", "Dorte", 
    "Dorte Bräuner", "Dr. Manfred und Gertrude Richter-Reichhelm", 
    "Dronningens Ferieby", "DS Buchungsservice", "Ejvind Koch", 
    "Elisesminde", "Ellen Ebsen", "Enjoy Resorts Marina Fiskenæs", 
    "Erik Bindslev", "Erik Kjer Hansen", "Erik Lind Jacobsen", 
    "Eva Nøhr og Ulrik Haastrup Strøm", "Evelin Weichert", "Fam. Packebusch", 
    "Fanø bad Ferielejligheder", "Finn Støy", "Fitting Landsbyferie Apartments", 
    "Frankrigsgade 10 Apartment", "Frankrigsgade 7 apartment", 
    "Fuglegårdsvej", "Fuglsang Apartments Langeland", "Gabriela Ionita", 
    "Gitte", "Give Apartment", "Give City Apartment", "GUESTapart - Aarhus", 
    "Guesthouse Sharon Suite", "Gösta Toft", "Hanne Tauber", 
    "Haramara Bed and Breakfast", "Hartmut Pousset", "Heidi Helsinghof", 
    "Heine Buus", "Heine Sort", "Helen Hohlmann", "Helene Ejsing", 
    "Helle", "Helle Andersen", "Helle Eriksen", "Helle Nexö", 
    "Henning Stengaard Mortensen", "Henriette & Mathias Merker", 
    "Henrik Beisheim", "Henrik Møhring Madsen", "Henrik Paludan", 
    "Henrik Paarup", "Herning City Apartments", "Herr Bahne Bahnsen", 
    "Holidayhome Rejsby close to Rømø", "Holmsborg Apartments", 
    "HostMinded", "hyldahl", "Inga Brodersen \\u002F Jesper Ravn Jensen", 
    "Jan Stampe Thomsen", "Jannie Buch", "Jannik Larsen", "Jeanett Ulrich", 
    "Jens Gudmundsson", "Jeppe Birch", "Jesper Bundgaard", "Jesper Helmuth Madsen", 
    "Jesper Levring", "Jesper Mogensen", "Jessel's Properties", 
    "Jette Bütow", "Jette Haar Iwersen & Arnd Wiegler", "Johanne Frey", 
    "Julien Ringdahl", "Jytte Brodersen", "Jørgen Christian Andersen", 
    "Jørgen Holst", "Jörgen Rasmussen", "jørn vilrik", "Kaj Iversen", 
    "Karina Madsen", "Karsten Buch", "Karsten Damborg", "Katerina Lind", 
    "Katja Brandt", "Katrina Schwartz", "Katrine Kühl Underbjerg", 
    "Kenneth Andreasen", "Kim Ochwat", "Kirsten Birkelund", "Kirsten og Claus Nielsen", 
    "Kjeld bjerg nielsen", "Kommandørgaarden Rømø", "Kresten Søgaard", 
    "Kristina Olsson", "L. Hougaard", "Langesø Slot Ferielejligheder", 
    "Lars Boel", "Lars Heerfordt", "Lars Johansen", "Lars Ole Hansen", 
    "Lars Thomsen", "Lasse Kaae", "Linda Andersen", "Lisbeth Strømkjær", 
    "Loran", "Lotte Reinhardt", "louise ulrich", "Lustrup Farmhouse", 
    "Lykke Fehmerling", "M. TARAN", "Maj Gran 6525", "Malene Vaamonde", 
    "Manuela und Gert Thimsen", "Marianne Boje", "Mark Ginge-Nielsen", 
    "Marliese Wessels", "Martin Steen Jensen", "Mary", "Mathias Kjems", 
    "Merete Maj-Sälzer", "Merete Maj Sälzer", "Mette Friis", 
    "Mette Jansen", "Mialy", "Michael Hansen", "Michael Riis og Kirsten Eriksen", 
    "Michael Sommer", "Michel Blanes", "Mie Lund", "Mie Petersen", 
    "Mikkel Kallesoe", "Monica Moreno", "Monika Brüggemann", 
    "Morten og Vibeke Petersen", "Nana Aukschun Nørsøller", "Nanna Hjul", 
    "Nichlas Heyde", "Nick Domdey", "Niels Jørgensen", "Niels Pedersen", 
    "Niklas", "Nis Boysen", "Nord Collection", "Novasol", "Nyhavn Apartments", 
    "Ole Fjordside", "Ole Madsen", "Olga Laux", "Orla und Martina Vognsen", 
    "Oscar Foss", "Oskar", "Owner \\u002F Property Manager", 
    "Paw Winther", "Penthouse", "Pernille Kjeldmann", "Peter", 
    "Peter Keldorff", "Peter Waldheim", "Peter Zeeman", "Petra Olesen", 
    "Petra Reimers-Behrmann", "Poul Erik", "Property Manager", 
    "Pyttegaarden Apartments", "Raimondas", "Rasmus", "Rikke", 
    "Rita Brix", "Rita Schönenberger Pedersen", "Ronnie Kloch", 
    "Rosenborg Hotel Apartments", "Sabine Schiffmann", "sabrina Salvati", 
    "Samir Maali", "Sandra Mikkelsen", "SECRA Bookings GmbH", 
    "Simon Roel", "Simona Rasmussen", "skærbækcentret", "Slotsgade 5", 
    "Sofie Bille", "Solveig Eike", "Sommerlykke", "Sonne und Strand", 
    "STAY Bryggen", "STAY Seaport", "Stefan Hansen", "Stefan Katic", 
    "Stefanos", "Stephanie Graf", "Stinne Hansen", "Studio Apartment in Højer", 
    "Studio Apartment Without Kitchen", "Susanne Digbeu-Larsen", 
    "susanne øgelund", "Svendlundgaard", "Søhuset Apartment", 
    "Sønderborg City Apartments", "Søren Christiansen", "Søren Peter Kvist", 
    "Tanja Hughes", "Terry Pedersen", "The Nordic Collection III", 
    "The Nordic Collection IV", "The Nordic Collection IX", "The Nordic Collection V", 
    "The Nordic Collection VI", "The Nordic Collection VIII", 
    "The Nordic Collection X", "Thomas Borg", "Thomas Michel", 
    "Thorkild Bentien", "Tina Halling", "Tina Hansen & Sven Marcussen", 
    "Tine Jørgensen", "Tonni", "Toppen af Danmark", "Toppen Af Danmark", 
    "Torben Jakobsen", "Tove Dyremose", "Tove Lund", "Travelopo", 
    "Ulla Kropf", "Ulrich Hansen,", "Ulrik Ahlefeldt-Laurvig", 
    "Ulrike Deubert-Gehrmann und Siegfried Pfitzner", "Valmuevej Apartment", 
    "Veras Allé", "Visitmors\\u002FMorsø Turistbüro", "Vitsøhus I\\u002FS", 
    "Warny Mandrup", "White Hart Lane House", "White House Hotel Apartments", 
    "Yrsa und Robert Behrmann", "aap@beststaycopenhagen.com"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(c(4L, 5L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 18L), c(1L, 6L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 14L, 17L), c(2L, 3L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L), 8L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```
````

Comment: You can try: `dat1[dat1$Company != 0, ]`

Comment: `filter(n() > 15 & Company != 0)`.

Comment: That is not working. I believe it is because all the variable in the column "Company" is different from zero.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example and expected output. This will make it easier for people to help you

Comment: All right I try again.. What I want is only to have the companies that have more than 15 rows in the data. If I use the filter function I can see which companies that is, but I would like to save them without having to use select for each company that have more than 15 lines in the data. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jackpetersen please provide a sample of your data for example by using dput() and specify your desired outcome (by editing your post)

Comment: I Have edited the post and hope this makes my problem clear.

Comment: did you mean `dat1[dat1$Pool != 0,]` instead ?

Comment: Yeah, when you tell R `!= 0`, you need to tell it which column you want to be not equal to 0. Perhaps, from the start, `filter(n() > 15 & Pool != 0)`

Comment: If you continue to have problems, please share **reproducible** data. Pictures of data are hard to work with. `dput` is a great way to share copy/pasteable data. `dput(droplevels(dat[1:20, ]))` is a nice way to share the first 20 rows of `dat`.

Comment: I have used the dput now.. And no I'm not meaning that the value of Pool column should be equal to zero. I only want those companies who appear more than 15 times in the column called company. I want to remove the rest of the companies.

Comment: I'm only interested in the company column in this case.

Comment: New guess: the first picture you posted was of a `table` output, (you didn't show the code, so that's just a guess), after filtering the data. Your data type is a `factor`, which we can see now in your `dput`, so the unused levels are not dropped automatically. The "0s" you keep referring to are 0 counts in the table, not 0s in the actual data. If all that is correct: use `droplevels` to drop unused factor levels: `data1 = dat %>% group_by(Company) %>% filter(n()>15) %>% droplevels()`

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! I just found another way of getting the same result using following: `ddply(dat, "Company",function(d) {if(nrow(d)>15) d else NULL})`

Comment: wow, @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- had already provided the answer while I was reaching the same conclusion in rstudio. Got confused at first because filter was working he just needed to remove the labels.

Comment: Yes, next time please show the code you use to generate the problem. If you had shown that you had used `table(dat1$Company)` that was showing the 0s you didn't like, we would have been able to answer very quickly. Instead, you kept talking about 0s, but the only 0s we could see in the data are in the `Pool` column, a big red herring.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your data in a df variable, i did the following:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(t)
df
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
df <- as_tibble(df)

new_df <- df %>% group_by(Company) %>% filter(n()>15) %>% droplevels()
summary(new_df$Company)
```

As you can see, without `droplevels()` even the factors with zero counts are shown as they are in level definition.